# Input date placeholder with current date

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

please tell me how to change place holder with current date

```
<input type="date" v-model="selectedDate" class="dateclass" placeholder="[method tu get currentdate]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
computed: {
     getDateStr(){
         let s = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      return s
    },
},
data(){
   return {
    type:'text'
 }
}



<input :placeholder="getDateStr" v-model="selectedDate"  class="dateclass" :type="type" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date">
```

Comment: why does the 'type' need to be 'text' in order for this to work?  why can't the type be 'date' as we'd expect, enabling the use of the date select popup?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<input type="date" v-model="selectedDate" class="dateclass" :placeholder="new Date().toLocaleDateString()">
```

Note that you need a colon (:) in front of placeholder.